# Probability of failing before a second condition

Tags: probability, dice

This question came up during a D&D game I was playing in and I found that I was unable to come up with an answer. I believe this should be a summation question, but I may be entirely off:

You roll a 20 sided die. A success is defined as rolling 16 or higher and failure is defined as rolling 15 or lower. You roll the die until 60 trials have been completed or you accumulate 6 failures. What is the probability of accumulating 6 failures, and how would you find the probability of lasting an arbitrary number of trials before accumulating 6 failures?

Comment: Good grief, who are they trying to defeat?! :-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the easiest first. You want the probability that in 60 rolls, you roll 16 or higher all but at most five times. That is a binomial probability. The probability of survival is given by this formula:

$$\sum_{k=0}^5 \dbinom{60}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{60-k}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{k} \approx 1\times 10^{-25}\%$$

Now, the probability that you can survive a given number of trials is:

You have 100% probability of surviving up to 5 trials. 
Probability that you survive up to $n$ trials (for $n\ge 6$):
$$\sum_{k=0}^5 \dbinom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n-k}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{k}$$

Probability you lose on the $n$-th trial:
$$\dbinom{n-1}{5}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n-6}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^6$$

Expected number of trials before finally succumbing to luck:
$$\sum_{n\ge 6}n\dbinom{n-1}{5}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{n-6}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^6 = 8$$

You can expect to fail by the eighth trial (on average).